# No matching function call to .....(std::string&)

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, snmp

So I am trying to initalize my variables to some value stored in a struct, but I keep getting this error.
I am utilizing the snmp++ library and I need to use some of the variables it provides such as OctstStr. Normally you can initialize it with the following:

```
Snmp_pp::OctetStr m_userName = Snmp_pp::OctetStr("username");
```

However it won't let me pass a string stored in a variable such as

```
std::string myUsername = "user";
Snmp_pp::OctetString m_userName = Snmp_pp::OctetStr(myUsername);
```

When ever I do i get the following error

```
error: no matching function call to Snmp_pp::OctetStr::OctetStr(std::string&)
```

Here is some of my code snippets

```
struct EthernetData{
   std::string userName;
   EthernetData() :
   userName("")
   {}
}
```

In another class lets call Main.cpp I am trying to initalize in the following

```
SnmpC::SnmpC(EthernetData ethernetData)
{
    m_userName = Snmp_pp::OctetStr(ethernetData.userName);
}
```

my header file main.hpp

```
private:
Snmp_pp::OctetStr m_userName;
```

Comment: What is OctetStr and OctStr? Be kind to post a [mcve] and the full error message.

Comment: @273K Sorry I have my code on another system, so I'm trying my best to transcribe the minimal amount to see the problem.  So basically OctetStr is part of the Snmp++ library. You pass it a string value and it packs the binary used to go across the wire. Normally you'd hard card the value in OctetStr("userName"), but using a variable seems to throw the error OctetStr(MyStringVariable)

Comment: Didn't you already ask about this trouble: [no matching function for call to Snmp_pp:OctetStr::OctetStr(Snmp_pp::OctetStr*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915272/)? Double-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: Yes, sorry that post was kind of messy so I wanted to clean it up and make it a bit more concise. My apologies :(

Answer (score 1):

[SNMP++ OctetStr](https://www.agentpp.com/doc/snmp++3.x/classOctetStr.html) does not have a constructor `OctetStr(std::string str)` but has `OctetStr(const char *str)`. Use:

```
Snmp_pp::OctetStr m_userName = Snmp_pp::OctetStr(ethernetData.userName.c_str());
```

It also has the assignment operator `OctetStr& operator= (const char *str)`, thus you can do it shorter:

```
Snmp_pp::OctetStr m_userName = ethernetData.userName.c_str();
```

---

If you took a look at the full error message, you would see the constructor candidates and likely would not ask the question.

Comment: Interesting I assumed that std::string("") and whatever resolves in ("") is also a std::string.

In the future to help my debugging efforts is there some sort of typeOf function in c++ that would expose what exactly I'm working with?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment. In the future to help your debugging efforts, read the error messages carefully and in whole.

Comment: Sorry I understand now, I was thinking that the message, "no matching function for call to Snmp_pp::OctetStr::OctetStr(std::string&)" was trying to tell me that I needed to de-reference the variable, or something to do with pointers. Not that I couldn't use std::string.

I was naive in thinking OctetStr("userName") and OctetStr(myUserNameVariable) were equivalent.